# How to insert on MySQL when no row affected on update in one request?

Tags: mysql

this is my request for update :

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET column_i_want_to_update = 'column value' 
WHERE id_which_is_not_primary_key_nor_unique = 'id value'
```

If 0 row is affected with this update, I want to run my insert request :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (column_i_want_to_update, id_which_is_not_primary_key_nor_unique) 
VALUES ('column value', 'id value')
```

But I want to perform that in one request instead of two. I've attempted this request :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id_which_is_not_primary_key_nor_unique, column_i_want_to_update) 
VALUES ('id value', 'column value') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE column_i_want_to_update = column_i_want_to_update
```

but this doesn't work because my id is not a primary key nor unique. Is there a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No solution in a single query form. Use stored procedure.

Comment: Is the combination of ('id value', 'colummn value') unique?

Comment: @C14L Yes, the combination of these two fields are uniques.

Comment: Then you can just add a `UNIQUE KEY` over both columns, and then `ON DUPLICATE KEY` should work. (I added as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique index over the two columns.

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` 
ADD UNIQUE `my_unique_index`
(id_which_is_not_primary_key_nor_unique, column_i_want_to_update);
```

Now the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use and if Expression

```
IF(expression ,expr_true, expr_false);
```

So under the expression use the

```
SELECT IF(( mysql_affected_rows(&mysql) >0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' 
END),'true','false');
```

or something similar

```
IF condition THEN
   statements;
ELSE
   else-statements;
END IF;
```